# iPhone make toolbar visible in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a UITableView has a subview of a UIView and I've added a toolbar on top of the UITableView so it should look like this:

[image]

However when I actually run it, it looks like this:

[image]

So for some reason the UIToolBar isn't showing up. I really don't know why, is anybody able to figure this one out? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've changed the simulated metrics like suggested and it still does not show up:

[image]

EDIT2: Here is a list of objects as requested by Raixer.

[image]

Comment: can you show the list of objects in your Interface Builder?

Comment: How do you list the objects in the interface builder?

Comment: Drag the left column so that it expands and shows a list instead of icons. That way you can see the hierarchy of your views.

Comment: Okay I've updated the post to include a list of objects.

Comment: Sorry I just woke up but my answer is right down there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. I have a similar setup in my app so I will show you what I did.

I setup a tab bar controller with navigation controllers in each tab (this gives me the navigation bar automatically that is why I use it). If you notice the View on the first tab is being loaded from another nib (that is what I am assuming you are doing). I did this by changing the view's class to my own view controller and then setting the name of the NIB file to load in the Inspector like this:

[image: TabBar with Navigation]
<sub>(source: [minus.com](https://k.minus.com/jbxHCoEjvAwOcD.jpg))</sub>

Then in my other nib file I only have this:

[image: Table View]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did that except I didn't have the navigation controller. I tried to add a navigation controller but it won't let me drag it into the Favourites view (The one with the table view). It will let me drag and add the navigation controller to any other view, but not that one.

Comment: Actually after a bit more fiddling around, it allowed me to add it. Thanks :)

Comment: I've got an additional issue, I've added a UIBarButtonItem, but I don't know how to define the action of it. When I try to Ctrl drag it, it doesn't allow me to set up an IBAction or anything.

Comment: If you want the TableView to handle the action from UIBarButtonItem you have to declare an IBAction in your TableViewController. Then CTRL+drag from it to the ViewController like this [link](http://k.minus.com/jn1j00Hkt378m.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you configured your nib file without counting with the height of the Tab bar.

The toolbar's height is 49 pixels. So when the view appears all your elements are moved 49 pixels up.

You should got to IB, open your View, go to Attributes Inspector, and in simulated metrics select Tab bar for Bottom Bar.

[image]

Comment: I've done that but it still doesn't show the toolbar, I've edited my post with another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will succeed with this approch. `UITableViewController` is very picky about adding subviews to its `UITableView`. However, you can have your `UITableView` handled by a standard `UIViewController` (just let IB point to a custom class inheritng from UIViewController). Add the table view to the controller's view as a subview and add the toolbar to the outer view.
Then you should be able to add subviews. `UITableViewController` gives you some convinience and functionality. If you can live without, UIViewController is no disadvantage. If you can't, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Another alternative to get the toolbar: put your table into a `UINavigationController`. That one comes with a toolbar (on top).

Comment: I tried the second alternative (the first one was difficult to follow) and it didn't work. I have a comment on the first alternative: The view controller is a UIViewController that inherits the table stuff(<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>).